# Do I have to put path for macs?

Tags: php, path, phpmyadmin, xampp

I add exactly address location of csv file inside the image below but it didn't work the way i expected? Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: "it didn't work" has never helped anyone anywhere at any time to get help. What does that mean? What error do you get?

Comment: select database and click on import and select file

Comment: please take a look at this document before posting on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve